# MySQL procedure exists, but doesn't

Tags: mysql, errors

I am attempting to add a stored procedure to a database that does not show that any exist in tree (Workbench):

[image]

As this screenshot of tree shows.

Also, executing:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS where Db = 'my_database_name';
```

returns 0 records.

But when I attempt to create a procedure like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `sp_myprocedure`(
            IN prm_id int,
            IN prm_active boolean
            )
BEGIN 
    
    # a select statement returning some records

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

throws error:

```
Error Code: 1304. PROCEDURE sp_myprocedure already exists   0.0097 sec
```

I then checked for corruption:

```
mysqlcheck
```

for the database in question and it returned `tables` - all ok:

```
...
my_database_name.my_table_name           OK
...
```

It does not appear to be corrupted, so I am very confused.

- MySQL 5.7.34
- Workbench 8.0.31

> What is going on here?

Executing

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.proc;
```

returns

```
CREATE TABLE `proc` (
  `db` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` enum('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE') NOT NULL,
  `specific_name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `language` enum('SQL') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SQL',
  `sql_data_access` enum('CONTAINS_SQL','NO_SQL','READS_SQL_DATA','MODIFIES_SQL_DATA') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CONTAINS_SQL',
  `is_deterministic` enum('YES','NO') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
  `security_type` enum('INVOKER','DEFINER') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DEFINER',
  `param_list` blob NOT NULL,
  `returns` longblob NOT NULL,
  `body` longblob NOT NULL,
  `definer` char(93) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `sql_mode` set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `character_set_client` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `collation_connection` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `db_collation` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_utf8` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db`,`name`,`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stored Procedures'
```

Comment: Have you tried running `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_myprocedure;` before the execution of the procedure creation?

Comment: @lemon - I could do that, but it does not answer my question as to why I am not finding the stored procedures in Workbench, and why this weird state.  I would like to understand this situation, not just brute force my way around it.

Comment: Look ```SHOW CREATE  PROCEDURE sp_myprocedure;```. Test ```CREATE  PROCEDURE databasename.sp_myprocedure;```.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using ??? Please run `SELECT VERSION() MySQLVersion;` and tell us.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - I have added the versions involved to the post.

Comment: Please run `SELECT COUNT(1) StoredProcCount FROM mysql.proc;`. What do you get ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - I think we're getting somewhere - there are a total of 195 procs across several databases.  When I executed `SELECT * FROM mysql.proc;` I encountered `Table 'proc' is marked as crashed and should be repaired`

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.proc\G` or `SELECT engine FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='mysql' and table_name='proc';`. The table should be InnoDB. Is it ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - No MyISAM.  See my post updates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142129/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-roy-hinkley).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix the table that stores the Stored Procedures

```
REPAIR TABLE mysql.proc;
```

This should clear it up.

Since the `mysql.proc` table is MyISAM, it probably got corrupted. This is easy to happen. When the header file for a MyISAM table (`proc.MYD`) does not have the correct number of open file handles written in it, it is marked as crashed.

You have a new problem. MySQL 5.7 should have InnoDB as the storage engine. You should convert that to InnoDB.

Comment: THANK YOU!  Your guidance is spot on!!!  That table was clearly corrupted.  All my procs for the db are now listing again.

Comment: I will consider ISAM --> InnoDB at a future date, but I've been thrown off schedule by this corruption and need to get back on task.